# NoClassDefFoundError on Google App Engine

Tags: eclipse, google-app-engine, noclassdeffounderror

I am developing a project on Eclipse Juno using both GWT and GAE.

My original project had all its packages and classes on the same project and it worked fine both on Development Mode and when uploaded to the Google App Engine on the Internet.

Then I created another project (on the same workspace) were I moved the classes that were generic so they could be used on other projects. I have not created a Jar file. Do I have to? I wish I could just keep my generic classes on another project without putting them on a jar file.

After a while I was able to create correct XXX.gwt.xml files on both projects and added the new project to the "Projects" tab of the main project properties (Project >> Properties >> Projects) to make the moved classes visible to the main project. The GWT compiler found those moved classes, translated them into Javascript code and the main project was able to execute them on the client side.

My problem is on the server side. No matter what I try the server part cannot find the moved classes and when trying to execute any of them it comes with the "NoClassDefFoundError" error  when running on the Development Mode (I have not tried to upload to the Google App Engine on the Internet yet).
If I comment out all the references to those classes on the server side the error does not show up, but of course I don't have their functionality.

Gaston Ceron

Comment: You don't have to make a JAR, but you have to somehow upload that code to AppEngine. Easiest is a JAR that you copy to WEB-INF/lib.

Comment: Thanks, I suspected that I would need the jar file after all.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you'll have to create a jar of the second project, and put it in the WEB-INF/lib folder.

If you can use maven or ant, you can probably set up appengine to compile the other project into a jar and use it as a dependency for the app engine project.

Comment: Thanks, I don't know much about Java and I was trying to avoid making a Jar file. Now I know better.